# Why does this func type conversion fail in Go?

Tags: go

**Context:** I'm trying to convert a type `func(*interface{}) bool` to a type `func(*string) bool`, but am running into a compilation error. Go complains that the type conversion is not possible, but doesn't explain why. Minimal repro is as follows:

**Code:**

```
type strIterFn func(*string) bool
func someFactory (_ []interface{}) func(*interface{}) bool {
  return func(_ *interface{}) bool { return true }
}

func main() {
  strs := []interface{}{"hello", "world"}
  strIterFn(someFactory(strs)) // --> this line fails to compile
}
```

**Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/oOSy50j_tKw**

Comment: What is the code supposed to do, and why do you think it should work?

Comment: The conversion is not possible because the signatures do not match.

Comment: `interface{}` doesn't mean "any type" it means literally `interface{}` and nothing else.

Comment: ^ That's helpful, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there is no type covariance in Go.

In the Go FAQ, it explains:

> ```
> Can I convert a []T to an []interface{}?
> ```
>
> Not directly. It is disallowed by the language specification because
> the two types do not have the same representation in memory. It is
> necessary to copy the elements individually to the destination slice.

This is an explanation for slices, but for functions it's the same idea.

---

Besides, I find your code sample odd. Why do you need `*interface{}`? It's a fairly esoteric use case to need a pointer to an interface.

Maybe the right approach here is to redesign? If you can describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, there could be alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, I'll look to redesign.